# How to setup GetStream for corporate intranet?

Tags: getstream-io

I'm looking to add a "company feed" to a corporate intranet SaaS application. More or less a timeline of posts very similar to facebook.

1) I think the Flat feed type is what I'd want for that but not sure.

2) I don't want users to have to "follow" one another. If you post on the company feed, everyone in the company should probably see it. How would you set this up on GetStream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes, a flat feed is what you'd want.

2) If the users don't follow each other, everyone in the company posts to the same feed, and the same feed is shown to everyone in the company, then the best option is probably to set up a single feed group (`timeline`, maybe), with one feed in it (`timeline:company1234`) that everyone posts to and reads from.

Then, whenever a user posts on the company's feed, you'll add an activity to the `timeline:company1234` feed, and whenever someone needs to read the feed, you'll retrieve the activities from the `timeline:company1234` feed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How does GetStream prevent someone from requesting a timeline for a different company?